# How to exclude some methods?

Tags: functions, algorithm

Can I exclude one or several methods from methods tried by a function?

When we use some 'algorithm-intensive' function, we can often specify whether we want to proceed according to the chosen method or let the algorithm choose the best (in some sense) one.
Consider, for example:

```
Classify[trainingset,Method->"DecisionTree"]
```

and

```
Classify[trainingset]
```

If, however, I would like to exclude some of the methods from the search, because they do not suit me for some reason.

Suppose I do not want these:

```
{"NearestNeighbors","LogisticRegression"}
```

Of course, the code containing the list of all remaining methods to be taken into account would be equally good.

Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you could try: SetOptions[Classify, Method -> {"DecisionTree", "GradientBoostedTrees", "Markov", 
"SupportVectorMachine"} or whatever methods you want to include, but I'm not sure if this would work. Other way would be to write a function which loops through the different methods, the ones that you want, using the above SetOptions function

Comment: I'm not sure this is really possible. Generally, I would expect these functions to have some way of determining the "best" method for a given input, but not necessarily a "second-best" one. So which method should it choose if the best method is excluded?